# Idle postgres processes taking up lots of memory

Tags: postgresql, memory, centos, centos6, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to figure out why ~30 idle postgres processes take up so much process-specific memory after normal usage. I am using Postgres 9.3.1 and CentOS release 6.3 (Final).
Using `top`, I can see that many of the postgres connections are using up to 300mb (average ~200mb) of non-shared (RES - SHR) memory:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 3534 postgres  20   0 2330m 1.4g 1.1g S  0.0 20.4   1:06.99 postgres: deploy mtalcott 10.222.154.172(53495) idle
 9143 postgres  20   0 2221m 1.1g 983m S  0.0 16.9   0:14.75 postgres: deploy mtalcott 10.222.154.167(35811) idle
 6026 postgres  20   0 2341m 1.1g 864m S  0.0 16.4   0:46.56 postgres: deploy mtalcott 10.222.154.167(37110) idle
18538 postgres  20   0 2327m 1.1g 865m S  0.0 16.1   2:06.59 postgres: deploy mtalcott 10.222.154.172(47796) idle
 1575 postgres  20   0 2358m 1.1g 858m S  0.0 15.9   1:41.76 postgres: deploy mtalcott 10.222.154.172(52560) idle
```

There are about 29 total idle connections. These idle connections keep growing in memory until the machine starts using swap, then performance grinds to a halt.
As expected, resetting the connection clears the process-specific memory.  The same number of connections on the same machine only use 20% of memory (with 0 swap) when I periodically reconnect.  What kind of information are these processes holding on to?  I would expect long-running, idle postgres processes to have similar memory usage to brand new, idle ones.

Worth noting: I am heavily using schemas.  On every request to my app, I am setting and resetting search_path.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What kind of information are these processes holding on to? I would expect long-running, idle postgres processes to have similar memory usage to brand new, idle ones.

There are actually quite a few things that Postgres will cache in local memory once it has loaded them:

- relcache (relation descriptors)
- catcache (system catalog entries)
- compiled trees for plpgsql functions

For most use cases, all of these add up to a negligible amount.  The key here was heavy usage of schemas and the effect on the relcache.  This database contains ~500 schemas, each with the same ~90 tables.  To Postgres, even though the schemas are all the same, this works out to 45,000 tables (500*90).

Each request cached some of the tables' relation descriptors in memory (most often in a different schema than the request before it), gradually filling up the relcache.  Unfortunately, [Postgres does not offer a way to limit the size of these caches](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1790015), as the overhead would probably be counterproductive for most use cases.

Possible solutions:

- Reconnect after a certain number of requests
- Add more memory
- Connection pooling to put a ceiling on the number of postgres connections using [pgpool-II](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer)

Thanks to Tom Lane and Merlin Moncure for help with this over the [Postgres mailing lists](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Debugging-shared-memory-issues-on-CentOS-td5782802.html).